# Cannot Login to Magento Admin

Tags: php, magento

Checked out a couple previous answers to this question but I haven't found a solution that has worked for me yet.

Applying past updates to a new clients Magento store, they had not been keeping up with patches but recently switched to our servers for hosting.

Turned compiler off. After applying patches and clearing caches/logging out after each upload, returned this error trying login to dashboard:

Any help getting me into backend would be much appreciated:

Mage registry key "_singleton/Mage_Core_Model_Domainpolicy" already exists

Trace:

```
#0 /home/pproduct/public_html/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /home/pproduct/public_html/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/Mage...', false)
#2 /home/pproduct/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Core_Model...')
#3 /home/pproduct/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#4 /home/pproduct/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(527): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#5 /home/pproduct/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#6 /home/pproduct/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#7 /home/pproduct/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#8 /home/pproduct/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /home/pproduct/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /home/pproduct/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /home/pproduct/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be done via DB change user privileges for correct store ID:
Try:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply, I'm pretty new to the Magento environment honestly. What would be the best way to initialize?

Comment: use mysql on php admin or cpanel to make sql query

Comment: is there a specific database I should be targeting?

Comment: you can get your db name at magento_root/app/etc/locale.xml file